# File Upload CakePHP 3.4

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-3.4

Im trying to get a simple file upload from a form to save in my webroot/img folder, however i'm having some difficulty.

This is the form in the view:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($productImage) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Add Product Image') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('product_id', ['options' => $products]);
        echo $this->Form->file('image', ['label' =>'','size'=>'50']); //Uploaded file
        echo $this->Form->control('image_path');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

And this is the function in the controller:

```
    public function add()
{
    $productImage = $this->ProductImages->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $image = $this->request->data['image'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($image,WWW_ROOT . '/img')) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('file upload successful'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->success(__('file upload unsuccessful'));
        }
        $productImage = $this->ProductImages->patchEntity($productImage, $this->request->getData());

        if ($this->ProductImages->save($productImage)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The product image has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The product image could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $products = $this->ProductImages->Products->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('productImage', 'products'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['productImage']);
}
```

move_uploaded_file keeps returning false, and I cant work out why.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Sam.

Comment: please on your debug mode and check for possible errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to care 2 things

### 1.Proper from declaration

Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form ( `['type' => 'file']`) in CakePHP form create to the. then your code will be

`<?= $this->Form->create($productImage,['type' => 'file']) ?>`
 Details [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#changing-the-http-method-for-a-form)

### 2. Upload image

Upload Image in proper way
using
 `$this->request->data['image']['name'];`

Comment: Yep that did it. Thanks alot!

Comment: Bonus for the doc link. It made me realise in my case, another form wasn't closed with `end()`. Making my new upload file form in that view not being treated as a file upload but as a regular one which the former one was `create()` as. Relevant quote from it: `Specifying a 'file' value for type, changes the form submission method to ‘post’, and includes an enctype of “multipart/form-data” on the form tag. This is to be used if there are any file elements inside the form. The absence of the proper enctype attribute will cause the file uploads not to function.`